# Unary Negation in C++

Tags: c++, negation

I am almost done with this program, but I am having trouble applying the unary negation function to it.

I have made a program based on calculating complex numbers and so far it works perfectly well, except for the whole negative numbers part. I can't seem to figure out how to make my unary negation to work in the code without it warning me and crashing on me with its runtime error.

In my h file, I have this:

```
Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs);
```

and in my cpp file, I attempted to create this from what I wrote above:

```
Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs)
{
    return Complex(-lhs);
}
```

The code I wrote on my cpp file gives me a **Warning C4717** error that says: *"'operator-': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow."* And of course, applying the number above would cause runtime error.

I'm sure some of you want the full code, so here it is: header, cpp, and the test file. :)

I appreciate the help.

**header file:**

```
#ifndef com_H
#define com_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


/********** CLASS **********/

class Complex
{

    //The BFFs: Stream Insertion and Operators//

    friend istream &operator >> (istream &lhs, Complex &rhs);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &lhs, const Complex &rhs);

private:

    float real, img;

public:
            //Complex Constructor//

    Complex(float new_real = 0.0, float new_img = 0.0);

            //Complex Set-and-Get Functions//

    void setComplex(float new_real, float new_img);
    float getReal() const { return real; }
    float getImg()  const { return img; }

            //Complex Functions//

    Complex &operator+=(const Complex &rhs);
    Complex &operator-=(const Complex &rhs);
    Complex &operator*=(const Complex &rhs);
    Complex &operator/=(const Complex &rhs);

};


/********** O P E R A T O R **********/



Complex operator+(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
Complex operator*(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
Complex operator/(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);

//COMPARISON OPERATORS*/

bool operator==(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
bool operator!=(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
bool operator<(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
bool operator<=(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
bool operator>(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);
bool operator>=(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs);

//NEGATION//
Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs);

#endif
```

**cpp file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "com.h"

using namespace std;

//
//***************** COMPLEX CONSTRUCTORS *****************//
//
Complex::Complex(float new_real, float new_img)
{
    real = new_real;
    img = new_img;
}

void Complex::setComplex(float new_real, float new_img)
{
    real = new_real;
    img = new_img;
}


//
//***************IF REAL NUMBER IS ZERO CHECK***************//
//

void checkNum(char ops, float new_img)
{
    char i = 'i';

    if (new_img == 0)
    {
        cout << "0";
    }

    else if (new_img != 1 && ops == '-')
    {
        new_img *= -1;

        cout << new_img << i;
    }

    else if (new_img == 1 && ops == '-')
    {
        cout << "-i";
    }

    else if (new_img == 1)
    {
        cout << i;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << new_img << i;
    }

}

//
//*****************STREAM INSERTIONS*****************//
//

istream &operator >> (istream &lhs, Complex &rhs)
{
    char ops;
    char i = 'i';

    lhs >> rhs.real >> ops >> rhs.img >> i;     //lhs is another name for cin

    if (ops == '-')
    {
        rhs.img *= -1;
    }

    return lhs;
}

ostream &operator << (ostream &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{
    char ops;
    char i = 'i';
    float new_real = rhs.real;
    float new_img = rhs.img;

    if (new_img < 0)
    {
        ops = '-';
        new_img *= -1;
    }

    else if (new_img >= 0)
    {
        ops = '+';
    }

    if (new_real == 0)
    {

        checkNum(ops, new_img);

        return  lhs << endl;

    }

    else if (new_img == 0)
    {
        return lhs << new_real;
    }

    else if (new_img == 1)
    {
        return lhs << new_real << " " << ops << " " << i;
    }

    else
    {
        return lhs << new_real << " " << ops << " " << new_img << i;
    }

    //  lhs << rhs.real << " + " << rhs.img << 'i';

}

//
//***************COMPLEX ARITHMETIC OPERATORS***************//
//***************** ( + | - | * | / |) ***************** //
//

// FORMULA for COMPLEX NUMBERS :: (a + bi)

Complex operator+(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{

    float a = lhs.getReal();
    float b = lhs.getImg();

    float c = rhs.getReal();
    float d = rhs.getImg();

    return Complex(a + c, b + d);

}

Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{

    float a = lhs.getReal();
    float b = lhs.getImg();

    float c = rhs.getReal();
    float d = rhs.getImg();

    return Complex(a - c, b - d);

}


Complex operator*(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{

    float a = lhs.getReal();
    float b = lhs.getImg();

    float c = rhs.getReal();
    float d = rhs.getImg();

    return Complex(((a * c) - (b * d)) , ((a * d) + (b * c)));


}

Complex operator/(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{

    float a = lhs.getReal();
    float b = lhs.getImg();

    float c = rhs.getReal();
    float d = rhs.getImg();

    //Numerator
    float myReal = (a * c) + (b * d);
    float myImg = (b * c) - (a * d);

    //Denominator
    float myDenom = (pow(c, 2) + pow(d, 2));

    return Complex(myReal / myDenom, myImg / myDenom);

}

//
//*****************COMPLEX OPERATORS EQUALS *****************//
//**************** ( += | -=  | *= | /= |) ***************** //
//

Complex &Complex::operator+=(const Complex &rhs)
{
    real += rhs.real;
    img += rhs.img;

    //*this = *this + rhs;

    return *this;
}

Complex &Complex::operator-=(const Complex &rhs)
{
    real -= rhs.real;
    img -= rhs.img;

    return *this;
}

Complex &Complex::operator*=(const Complex &rhs)
{
    real *= rhs.real;
    img *= rhs.img;

    return *this;
}

Complex &Complex::operator/=(const Complex &rhs)
{
    real /= rhs.real;
    img /= rhs.img;

    return *this;
}


//
//******************COMPLEX OPERATORS COMPARISON*****************//
//**************** ( == | != | < | <= | > | >= |)*****************//
//

bool operator==(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{
    if (lhs.getReal() == rhs.getReal() && lhs.getImg() == rhs.getImg())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool operator!=(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

bool operator<(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{
    if (lhs.getReal() <  rhs.getReal() || lhs.getReal() == rhs.getReal() && lhs.getImg() < rhs.getImg())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool operator<=(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{
    return ((lhs < rhs) || (lhs == rhs));
}

bool operator>(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs <= rhs);
}

bool operator>=(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs < rhs);
}

Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs)
{
    return Complex(-lhs);
}
```

**main file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "com.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    Complex  userValue;

    cout << "Enter a complex value (a + bi): ";

    cin >> userValue;

    cout << "Negated: " << -userValue << endl;

    cout << "Addition:  " << userValue + Complex(0.0, 0.0) << endl;

    if (Complex(-6, 5.2f) == userValue)
        cout << "Wow! It's equal." << endl;

    return  0;

}
```

UPDATE 1: Wow! I just tested it again and it actually crashes on any number I put, positive AND negative lol! But when I comment the following codes out...
from main

```
//  cout << "Negated: " << -userValue << endl;
```

from header file

```
Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs);
```

from cpp file

```
Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs)
{
    return Complex(-lhs);
}
```

...it still works (without the negative numbers of course.)

Comment: Are you aware of `std::complex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, you're calling your overloaded function recursively. Instead you want to be calling the constructor with the proper arguments:

```
Complex operator-(const Complex &lhs)
{
    return Complex(-lhs.real, -lhs.imag);
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast! Thanks! I appreciate it! :D